# composer why: what does this output means?

Tags: composer-php

```
λ composer why php-http/client-common
sentry/sentry  3.17.0  requires   php-http/client-common (^1.5|^2.0)
sentry/sentry  3.17.0  conflicts  php-http/client-common (1.8.0)
```

What does this mean? Could you please explain?

In which way, `sentry/sentry` could require two times the same package (`php-http/client-common`)?

Comment: It doesn't tell you that it requires the same package twice, but that it has a conflict with a specific package version

Comment: Could you add some details please? Why should be a conflict ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the [`composer why` / `depends` command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#depends-why) you've shared does not reflect that `sentry/sentry` requires the package twice, but that it requires a specific range of versions (which is `^1.5|^2.0` in the first line), and that it conflicts with a different set of versions (which is `1.8.0`).

Have a look at the repository of `sentry/sentry` for more details. The conflict has been added in a [pull request](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/pull/681) more than four years ago with the following description:

> In #658 I did found an issue with php-http/client-common 1.8.0, precisely php-http/client-common#109. The problematic code is now reverted, so we can reduce the conflict constraint to the only bugged version.

Comment: You pointed me to the right place. The full answer should include a link to: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/pull/681/files/0f1c3a3d923c13adaa3571720c122bcc690b61a5 . Because it's an explicit conflict state in their composer.json to dictate this conflict.